# Overriding property in maven archetype integration test

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm generating a project from an archetype and I have a property in pom of this generated project (archetype-resources/pom):

```
  <properties>
    <myProperty>productionValue</myProperty>
  </properties>
```

and the following surefire configuration:

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>
            -Djava.library.path=${myProperty}
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

I want `myProperty` to be overridden with value from my archetype pom when I run ITs and stay the same when users generate this project. How do I do that?

I tried setting it in `archetype.properties` file, but it has a variable in it:
`myProperty=${project.basedir}/IT/path`.
I want `${project.basedir}` to be a basedir of archetype project in case of ITs, not of generated project, which is not the case when I do it like that.

Another way I tried is to use plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-archetype.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
              <configuration>
                <properties>
                  <myProperty>${project.basedir}/IT/path</myProperty>
                </properties>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But it didn't work as well, `myProperty` in pom of generated project is not changed. What is it that I'm doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have put

```
<configuration>
  <properties>
    <myProperty>${project.basedir}/IT/path</myProperty>
  </properties>
</configuration>
```

under `<execution>` tag and not `<plugin>`. After I did that it worked as expected.